# Can multiple ActionServers share a goal callback?

Tags: ros, action-server, callback, actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have an issues where I try to make two ActionServers share a single callback method (on different topics though), but for some reason only one of the servers (the one created latest) sets up the action topics.

Is it not possible for multiple action servers to share a single callback method?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/89026/can-multiple-actionservers-share-a-goal-callback?/) by [Rasmus](https://answers.ros.org/users/6846/rasmus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2013-10-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would think it's possible as I've used a single callback for multiple subscribers quite a few times.  And I think ActionServers just use subscribers under the hood.  How about posting some code so we could help?

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2013-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0